# Encoding for OrientDB (can't send a literal string)

Tags: python, character-encoding, orientdb

I have the next problem. I need to create a vertex with a propertyA with a value 'المساء'. The problem is from python, python CAN'T send the string 'المساء' so...

I know I need to do a encode, like the next:

```
>>>a = 'المساء'
>>>b = a.encode('cp270')
>>>print b
>>>'\x9f\xe9\xea\xab\x9f\x98'
```

But with this encode OrientDB won't work. I think that I need an ascii encode.

There is the problem (without response):
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/5860

Anyone that know about OrientDB can help me? Thank in advance!

Comment: What version of OrientDB you're using, please?

Comment: My DB version is 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using python I can do this:

```
>>> a = 'غريبديالى#مخيسةالعز'
>>> type(a)
<type 'str'>
>>> b = a.decode('utf8')
>>> b
u'\u063a\u0631\u064a\u0628\u062f\u064a\u0627\u0644\u0649#\u0645\u062e\u064a\u0633\u0629\u0627\u0644\u0639\u0632'
>>> print b
غريبديالى#مخيسةالعز
```

So, if I put a query like the next will create a vertex with the next result:

```
query = 'create vertex v content {"property":"%s"}' %b
```

[image]

Comment: The other form is using a JSON query and not a SQL query. It is very simple, {"command": "create..."} and doing json.dumps(content)    =)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with this code with orientDb version 2.2.7

```
import pyorient 

db_name='MyDb'

print("connection to the server...")
client=pyorient.OrientDB("localhost",2424)
client.set_session_token(True)
session_id=client.connect("root","root")

client.db_open( db_name, "admin", "admin" )

myFunction = 'insert into v(name) values("المساء")'
client.command(myFunction);

client.db_close()
```

and it worked for me

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: With create vertex and using the arabic character as a parameter it is not working :(

Comment: I tried it and didn't work but from Studio it worked.
Could you open an issue on github ?

Comment: In github the issue is broken, it is open since one year (more or less). I know that in Studio it works but... need it in python or Java =S

Comment: see my response pls =)